# Equivalent of [Bind] in vb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Is there an equivalent to C#'s MVC 
`[Bind(Include="Title,Description")]`
in VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it's `<Bind(Include:="Title,Description")>`